# How to use bg in grDevices::pdf to cover the entire page when paper != special?

Tags: r

When I change the value of paper parameter in pdf() from default value 'special' to something else (for example a4 or a4r), bg color does not cover the entire page.

I have tries changing the width, height and pagecentre parameters, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
grDevices::pdf("test.pdf", pagecentre = T, bg = "grey", onefile=TRUE, paper = "a4r", height = 12, width = 18)
plot(1:5,1:5)
dev.off()
```

Background color when paper style is 'special':
[Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgVKs.png)

Background color when paper style is not 'special':
[Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Evs.png)